# How to publish APIs?

Tags: java, api-design

How can I publish an API with Java? In languages like C or C++ it is really quite easy because you can simply divide headers from code, but in Java this is a complete different story. So I know that there is no real way in Java you can obfuscate your code, even if you "obsfuscate" it, because it can be easily decompiled and analyzed. But if I don't simply can distribute headers to someone, what is the preferred way to publish a API in Java? I don't have special needs because I am in the beginning of the designing process so I am really dynamic and I would like to know all alternatives I have.

Comment: I would distribute it as a JavaARchive (JAR).

Comment: It wasn't really the technical question on how to publish itself, but rather how to design the API, and if I should include a complete running copy of the program or if I can just publish some compilable jar, which hasn't the capability to run my whole program.

Comment: Either way it is best to program to interfaces and it is best to separate those from the implementation in an independent module (and thus independent jar).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A clean way is to define your API purely in Java interfaces, include those into a separate API module and make implementation module depend on the API module. This does not provide the same functionality as separating C++ header files, but it is a good idea to program to interfaces anyway completely separating those from a particular implementation.

Comment: However, it is probably not a good idea to code to interfaces simply to hide the code of a class.  Interfaces are more designed for use when there is a *true* interface - i.e. - the is (or could be) more than one implementation for the given class.  I have seen way too much code where every single class has its own interface.  It creates a lot of clutter.  If you are really just trying to publish the API, javadoc and jar are the way to go.

Comment: It is indeed not a good idea to code to interfaces just to hide the implementation as it simply leads to generating extra unnesessary piles of code, and my recommendation was not meant so. The main benefit is rather a clean contract for the functionality which evolves much slower (the contract) than the actual implementation, thus providing (external) users of the API an improved stability and clarity of their own code base. It would not be surprising to see the current version of the API at e.g. 1.2.2 and the current version of the implementation at e.g. 1.2.35...

Comment: I thought that was what you meant, but it appears as though the OP is mostly interested in hiding proprietary code from distribution (as with C++ headers), so I thought I would mention it.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to publish your API as header files. Everything the developer needs is already in the JAR. If you want to publish documentation publish the java docs of the code.

Comment: This does not address the original question

Comment: @OlegS. Yes it does, providing header files is about providing the available API. That's simply not needed when using Java.

Comment: It depends strongly on how one defines API. For me it is: ["An application programming interface (API) specifies how some software components should interact with each other"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_programming_interface), and in order to define how components of software interact with each other one does not need to have an implementation, interface is sufficient. Surely if interfaces are used at random or not used at all, then there is no need to separate them into a standalone module. Your is about packaging Java code, and as there are also WARs it is not general.

Comment: @OlegS. You're right, it doesn't has to have an implementation. Doesn't change the fact that I thought OP asked how he can provide them. And providing only the interfaces through a WAR/EAR/etc. instead of a JAR is not common, to say the least. Who should do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can obfuscate your code using a professional java obfuscator.  Then it is not easily decompiled and readable.  You can then publish your jars and javadocs like others have mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

You could split your library into multiple jars and provide one with the classes and interfaces that form the api and another one that contains the implementations of those interfaces.

However, note that the hastle might not be worth it. Why exactly would you try and obfuscate code the users of that api would need anyways? What I mean is, that whoever would use your api would also need the implementations of the interfaces to run the application, so they'd still be able to decompile your code.

Generating an api-only jar would help with separating api and implementation though (which means you could replace the implementation or prevent accidential direct access to the implementation).